# Making an angular statusbar directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

im looking to implement a directive to display status messages in my ionic angular app.. the idea is that i define a bunch of standard status messages in my template as follows and it's inspired by the stock `ng-switch` directive..

```
<status-bar code="statusCode" onShow="onStatusShow" onHide="onStatusHide">
    <status-message when-code="OK" style="calm" timeout="3000">My HTML message</status-message>
    ...
    ...
    <status-message when-complex style-field="style" text-field="text" timeout-field="timeout" />
</status-bar>
```

my requirements are these:

### status-bar

1. the directive should bind to `$scope.statusCode` and depending upon its string value, it should activate one of the sub-directives except the `when-complex` one..
2. however, if i assign an object to `$scope.statusCode`, it should activate the `when-complex` directive if defined..
3. the directive also exposes an `onShow` and `onHide` callbacks..
4. when changing the value of `$scope.statusCode`, the previously active sub-directive should be completely hidden before showing the newly active one.. (animations)

### status-message

1. `style` and `timeout` attributes are optional and will default to `'stable'` and `null` respectively..
2. the `timeout` attribute will cause this sub-directive to show for a short time before clearing `$scope.statusCode`..

whereas i can write very simple directives, this one is proving to be a bit beyond me.. ive seen the source of `ng-switch` and its confusing.. i have tried myself as well but i havent gotten really far with this no matter how much ive tried.. im not posting my code approaches here not for the lack of trying but for the sake of cluttering and relevance..

so i was wondering if maybe someone could come up with a possible basic approach on `codepen` or `plunkr` that i can use as a base for expanding upon (since this is just a simplified explanation of what i intend to do with this directive).. or atleast point in the directions i need to go in..

Answer (score 0):

after a night of brain-storming and coding punctuated by coffee and smoke breaks.. ive managed to make it work.. once again keeping ng-switch as a base.. the code is a bit long.. and i changed a few requirements along the way for better usability.. and some requirements like #2 and #3 dont work yet.. but im pretty sure ill make it work as well..

so if anybody is having a similar issue or is interested in my solution.. i can post it here.. :)